# How to set a field in oppty based on a parameter of it's products?

Tags: trigger, workflow, field-update

I need to check a CB on an oppty, when any of it's products are of a certain character.

Our products have a CB named: 3D

If an oppty, has any such 3D product, I want/need to check the CB: is_3D - on the oppty

My first thought was to use a workflow and field update - but that fails since I can't have any criteria, and the product 3D field does not come to effect here. I need that the update will be both ways. so, if I remove the last 3D product from the oppty, the CB is unchecked. (As Girbot mentioned, the workflow on OpportunityProduct does work)

[image]

Another thought is to use a trigger (which is a valid option) - on save/edit - if exists 3D product - CB = true. (here needs to make sure that I don't accidentally remove a checked sign if delete/remove an oppty - can become a real issue)

I am looking for alternate ways if possible?

Comment: I don't understand why you can't use a workflow rule on OpportunityProduct, wouldn't the criteria be something like:  Product2.CustomCD__c = True  (assuming the CB is on Product2 and not OpportunityLineItem).

Comment: thanks, that solves one problem, post as answer so I can vote up, but this does not work for the complete +/- 3D product.

Comment: Sorry I don't under the +/- bit (Monday morning). Do you need the Opty.CB to be unchecked when they no matching line items? Maybe you want to look at a roll up summary field on Opportunity (using the same criteria as the comment above) then a custom CB formula on Opportunity. So if RSF > 0 = True?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this approach would work. I'm assuming the 3D checkbox is on Product2.

You could add a formula CB or a custom CB with a workflow rule on OpportunityLineItem creation to be checked when `Product2.CB = True`, for demo purposes called `olicb__c`

Then add a roll up summary field on the Opportunity for OpportunityProrducts where `olicb__c = True`

You will now have the count of the OLIs where`olicb__c = True`. From here you may be happy with just the count showing, or you could add another check box formula on Opportunity like `rsf__c > 0 = True`

There is a potential limitation to this and that is if you need to fire anything else off the checkbox formula on the Opportunity...as a formula field cannot trigger a workflow rule off on it's own.