# Can I force a recalculation of objects?

Tags: custom-field, automation

**Addendum** to [How to set a field in oppty based on a parameter of it's products?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/55628/how-to-set-a-field-in-oppty-based-on-a-parameter-of-its-products)

I have a new CB for our product object.

a workflow rule, updates the opportunity product object, when it's created.

I have added a new CB, Rule and field update for our Opportunity Object.

Is there a way to have ALL older opportunities get the new values from that? from manual tests, this happens when the "EDIT ALL" on the products related list is used. NOT when just Edit/Save the opportunity.

The new CB will only get updated when an oppty is edited. How can I achieve that?

Comment: "new CB for our product object" == new checkbox field for the product object?

Comment: Can you clarify the last two sentences? I gather you need to save/edit the opportunity product (OpportunityLineItem) to get the checkbox field on the opportunity to get the correct value? Or is it the Opportunity that needs to be saved?

Comment: It's the line items that need to be edited. Than they cause the opportunity check box to be filled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the easiest approach would be to export all the OpportunityLineItems (Products) that you need to update (via a report or dataloader export, making sure you include the OpportunityLineItem.Id), then update the .csv (new columen CB=True I assume) and use the dataloader to update the OpportunityLineItems.

You could propbably do this with an execute anonymous script if you were comfortable with this. I do this occasionally but normally prefer the dataloader approach as I then have a record (the .csv file) of the changes I've made if I wish to roll it back or ever need to refer to it.

[OP]: Used Dataloader to export, and simply update back just with OpportunityLineItems ID's. That triggered the needed CB workflow etc.

Answer (score 2):

[@Girbot's answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/56060/102) to use the data loader or anonymous Apex seems reasonable for a one off process.

Another option would be to create a batch job over a SOQL query that finds all the OpportunityLineItem records that need to be saved. This might be a bit heavy handed if you only need to do it once. The benefit will depend on how many records you are dealing with.

Answer (score 1):

This answer the question: how can I update a CB on Opportunity every time I update a Product CB, provided I already have a mechanism to update the CB on Opportunity Line Items whenever their Product CB value changes. Posted question was not very clear.

Couldn't a mix of filtered Rollup and Triggers (on Opportunity object) make the job?

I mean, if you have a checkbox on Opportunity Product which is bound to change after any update on its related Product, and a filtered Rollup on the Opportunity object, which counts the amount of Opportunity Products with CB value equals to TRUE, then any change in the number of "3d Products" in an Opportunity will trigger a change in the Rollup count, and therefore fire the Opportunity Trigger.

In the Trigger you could then easily handle the logic for the "some of the products have become a 3d product!" event, on an Opportunity per Opportunity basis.

Answer (score 1):

*Posting a second answer/comment after clarifications received. Don't consider my other answer (@Girbot: I'm sorry if I practically gave here the same answer you gave on the previous OP question - I had a misunderstanding on this one, did not fully read the previous one... but I swear the similarity of my answers with yours was unintentional :).*

Other people have answered well enough regarding the options available if the OP wants to achieve a one-off process.

I don't know for sure what the OP Use Case is, and it could be in his company the Product CB value is changed frequently and old Opportunities are required to be always kept up to date after Products. In this case, or if in general it is intention to have a "continuous link" in time between the Products CB value and Opportunities/Opp Line Items CB value (and not a one-off update of them), then it's maybe worth to mention that would be required setting up a Trigger on the Product object (additional to what's already there) to automatically propagate any Product 3D CB update to their related Line Items (and Opportunities).

Comment: Nice. But i need it as a one timer. Once that's up, the workflow rules will take care of the rest.